# Public REST Service Access Error

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, apexrest, rest-service

I am moving a guest user sites page REST service from a sites page implementation to a public guest community.  It worked fine as a sites page REST service but I am having trouble porting it to a guest community.

I am getting the following aura error when I port it to a public community:

**"Invalid request, post must use JSON"**

I AM passing JSON in the body:

```
{"account":{"alias":"revenova"},"event":{"load_id":"SC1-252751","load":{"external_id":"a0i17000003pWqxAAE"},"type":"approved","id":14035638,"invoice":{"id":14035638,"load":{"external_id":"a0i17000003pWqxAAE","shipments":[],"customer":{"external_id":"0014100000HJzMTAA1"}},"state":"approved","number":"Load-252751","date":"2020-06-23","date_to_pay":"2020-07-23","amount_to_pay":1000.0,"source_invoice_amount":1000.0,"currency":"USD","approved_at":"2020-06-23T14:32:06.022Z","quickpay":false,"payment_strategy":"direct","extracted_fields":{"BOL":"676859012"},"note":null,"line_items":[],"shipped_items":[],"email_messages":[{"subject":"Freight Bill","received_at":"2020-06-23T14:28:07.687Z"}],"submission":null,"approver":{"email":"dcraigmile@revenova.com"},"processor":{"email":"dcraigmile@revenova.com"}},"carrier":{"external_id":"0014100000HJbDuAAL"},"documents":[{"id":377346889,"type":"invoice","proof_of_delivery":false,"url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/1d8de1ae-24a1-4c97-9c1f-8325ea267dce","fingerprint":"638d942a5e712e18144229854927588b375003b3","pages":[{"png_url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/1d8de1ae-24a1-4c97-9c1f-8325ea267dce/pages/390784701.png"}],"load":{"external_id":"a0i17000003pWqxAAE"},"shipments":[],"visibility":{"carrier":true,"customer":false}},{"id":377346892,"type":"proofOfDelivery","proof_of_delivery":true,"url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/e3196fee-76b5-4181-a9fd-d9dccc4ceb18","fingerprint":"3c863b3c3a10c3929e22a122127ccae211c38763","pages":[{"png_url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/e3196fee-76b5-4181-a9fd-d9dccc4ceb18/pages/390784703.png"}],"load":{"external_id":"a0i17000003pWqxAAE"},"shipments":[],"visibility":{"carrier":true,"customer":true}}],"combined_document_urls":[{"type":"invoice","url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/combined/cached/7b82d040-566e-4059-895b-e7d3fe33355f","proof_of_delivery":false,"pages":[{"png_url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/1d8de1ae-24a1-4c97-9c1f-8325ea267dce/pages/390784701.png"}],"visibility":{"carrier":true,"customer":false}},{"type":"proofOfDelivery","url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/combined/cached/4808a140-6f5b-4b74-84d6-debe0a922de0","proof_of_delivery":true,"pages":[{"png_url":"http://api.hubtran.com/downloads/documents/e3196fee-76b5-4181-a9fd-d9dccc4ceb18/pages/390784703.png"}],"visibility":{"carrier":true,"customer":true}}],"remit_to":{"name":"AAA Cooper Transportation - SC1","address_line_1":"","address_line_2":null,"city":"","state":"","postal_code":"","country":""}},"text":"Load SC1-252751 approved"}
```

The inbound POST URL looks something like this:

https://partial1-revesc1.cs22.force.com/api/s/services/apexrest/rtms/tmslistener?org=00D17000000ExxYEAS&source=HubTran&pwd=KaZkiGc7HBHxxx

and the code like this:

```
@HttpPost
global static String doPost() {

    try {
```

...

Once again it works fine from a sites page but produces this error from a guest community.

Thanks for your help or any ideas....

Comment: It is a packaged web service, by the way.

Comment: Did you use the header `Content-Type: application/json`? Salesforce should complain if you forget that part.

Comment: Yes I am setting that (in Postman so I can see everything).  No difference. Thanks for jumping on this for me.

Comment: <body class="auraError auraError">
 <div class="auraMsgBox auraLoadingBox" id="auraLoadingBox">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="spinner"></div><span>Loading</span>
 </div>
 <div class=" auraForcedErrorBox" id="auraErrorMask">
  <div class="auraErrorBox" id="auraError"><span><a class="close" id="dismissError">×</a>Sorry to interrupt</span>
   <div id="auraErrorMessage">Invalid request, post must use JSON</div>
   <div id="auraErrorStack"></div>
   <div class="auraErrorFooter"><a href="?" id="auraErrorReload">Refresh</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The darn '/s/' was this issue.  When I eliminated that it worked:

https://partial2-revesc1.cs22.force.com/api/services/apexrest/rtms/tmslistener?org=00D1700000xxx9EAC&source=HubTran&pwd=KaZkiGc7HBxxxx

Answer (score 0):

You're using an incorrect endpoint. The base endpoint for Apex REST is `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest` where `yourInstance` is the instance name or domain name of the org that hosts your site or community.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but no it needs to route via the guest user community URL or a session token is required.